# How to use or install MagickWand on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, imagemagick

I have problem with magickwand and python and Mac OX X.

When I'm importing it I get the error:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found. You probably had not
installed ImageMagick library. Try to install:   brew install imagemagick
```

```
brew install imagemagick Warning: imagemagick-6.8.9-1 already installed
```

Answer (score 12):

To get Wand working with imagemagick 7:

```
brew install imagemagick
echo 'export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/homebrew/opt/imagemagick/' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/imagemagick/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: For Apple Silicon (Apple M1) users, this works as the homebrew directory is different

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as well (Apple M1). Got to restart the terminal after adding the workaround.

Answer (score 10):

```
brew uninstall --force imagemagick

brew install imagemagick@6

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Answer (score 4):

So, the actual problem is :

> If your Python in not installed using MacPorts, you have to export MAGICK_HOME path as well. Because Python that is not installed using MacPorts doesn’t look up /opt/local, the default path prefix of MacPorts packages.

[from wand doc](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac)

And the solution they provide is :

> $ export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/local

Comment: easy_install doesn't have this package. I have imagemagick in this folders:

`/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick
/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/imagemagick
/usr/local/opt/imagemagick` is it correct?

Comment: try `easy_install MagickWand`, which is the Python version of imagemagick

Comment: The same error: 
`from wand.image import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/wand/api.py", line 161, in <module>
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install imagemagick`

Comment: ah ok, so try this : `export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/local` (in bash). If it's not working I don't know. (except try install it with macport)

Comment: Last try : write `export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/local` in ~/.bash_profile; then write in the shell : `source ~/.bash_profile`; then start your python session and do your stuff. If it's still not working, install macport and install imagemagick with it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Gowtham's & jrjc's answers, here's how I got the Wand python package to work using homebrew:

```
brew install imagemagick@6

echo 'export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

There's a few things to note here:

- wand at the time of this writing doesn't yet support imagemagick 7, see https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues/316 .
- MAGICK_HOME seems to be the better way to set the variable - it's mentioned in the [wand docs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac) as jrjr's answer mentioned, and if you're really curious you can see how Wand looks for things in [api.py](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/wand/api.py#L61) under the library_paths method. I couldn't get Gowtham's approach of exporting the bin directory to work.

Comment: Lifesaver! Turns out `brew upgrade` burned me on this one. Your tip to revert to version 6 was the solution.